# MySQL PDO query LIKE with PIPES

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pipe, sql-like

I have a PDO statement which is supposed to look for data with pipes around it, I have multiple id's stored in a single column. I know this isn't great but it seems the logical way to store the data.

Column content example |1|3|4|5|14|76|

So I want to find every line in the database with 3 in it. I use a php form to post or get 3

```
    $getthis = $_GET['getthis'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE types LIKE '?' ORDER BY name";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute('%|$getthis|%');
    while ($data = $q->fetch()) { do something }
```

Its not good, Ive tried various ways of doing this but I fail miserably every time.

Thanks for your help in advance and great site by the way! Its helped me loads

EDIT - Thanks for your help, I cant really change the structure unless I limit the number of sub-categories an item should be under. As this is what this column contains (so socks could be under footware[1] and footprotectors[4] and possibly 20 other subcats

Ill try this method 'find_in_set' but im confused as to why it needs to be higher than a zero?? Thanks again!

Comment: `REGEXP` could work here.

Comment: `table` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and should be set inside backticks. If that is in fact the code you are using.

Comment: no just used table to give an idea of what Im trying to do. Seems that find in set doesn't like my table.

Comment: @user2787636 Ok, just making sure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE find_in_set('$getthis', replace(types, '|', ',')) > 0
ORDER BY name
```

#### But you really should change the DB structure!

Comment: Wow - a response in 3 minutes! Forums are now dead - Im converted to stackoverflow :)